# Do I need to fflush or close a file before calling stat on it?

Tags: c, file, stat

After opening a file for writing:

```
FILE *file = fopen("./file", "w");
```

Can I assume the file was created immediately? Is it safe to call:

```
 stat( "./file", info);
```

Or should I better:

```
 fflush(file);
```

or

```
 fclose(file);
```

beforehand?

Edit: Assume non NULL file after fopen call

Comment: Well, first of all, definitely check for `file != NULL`. If it is `NULL`, there is no file. I can't answer the other part though.

Comment: You might be able to do `fstat(fileno(file), &info);` while the file is still open.

Comment: fstat seems like a possibility. I can't find documentation on whether it guarantees that for example an inode read from a file descriptor will be the one stored on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fopen manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fopen.html) says:

> If mode is w, wb, a, ab, w+, wb+, w+b, a+, ab+, or a+b, and the file
>   did not previously exist, upon successful completion, the fopen()
>   function shall mark for update the st_atime, st_ctime, and st_mtime
>   fields of the file and the st_ctime and st_mtime fields of the parent
>   directory.

So I think it is safe to stat on the file just after a successful fopen call.

Comment: Hm, I have to assume then that the OS is not required to set and stick with an inode at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, logically we could do it. As opening a file for writing in read-only filesystem fails. This indicates that fopen()/open() does required checks. Other way to confirm is this by opening file with **x similar to O_EXCL flag of open()**.

Answer (score 1):

If the call to [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fopen.html) is successful then it means that the file is created. The file may not be committed ( flushed ) to the disk though. But you need not worry about this as the next call to [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) will fetch the file from the kernel buffer.

So an [`fflush`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fflush.html) or an [`fclose`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fclose.html) is not required in this particular case.

The few times where in you need to scratch your head about flushing to disk is when there is a probability of a system crash. In this case if you haven't committed data completely to the disk using something like [`fsync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fsync.html), then there might be probable data loss upon next system restart.